# How to assign define role to group creator in groups created with the Group module?

Tags: 8, group

I am using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group)  module. Whenever a new group is created, member is added to that group with role `none`.

I want to assign a role to a group when a user creates a group. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The latest beta release of the group module (8.x-1.0-beta5) includes that functionality.

Download, install, run DB updates and go the the settings page for the group type.